# Bootstrap - Cards not working properly

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am following the examole from the first example on this page https://mdbootstrap.com/components/cards/ (trying to get same output)

```html
<!--Card-->
    <div class="card">
    
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20%282%29.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body">
            <!--Title-->
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <!--Text-->
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->
```

However, all i get is this ? any suggestions

[image]

Comment: Can't understand what you want.. Please explain more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a different bootstrap link, hope this matches with your requirement

**Try this**

```css
.card-body{
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<!--Card-->
    <div class="card">
    
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20%282%29.jpg" width="550rem" alt="Card image cap">
    
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body">
            <!--Title-->
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <!--Text-->
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->
    </div>
```

Comment: Still doesnt work, doesent give output like in website example

Comment: did you run my snippet?

Comment: yes, it still doesnt give the same as the website if you have a look at the link i gave in the question

Comment: try now, i think you need some spacing in the content. You can adjust it width from the image

Comment: also you are having multiple cards, you can limit the card by max-width property.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not pure bootstrap, you need add reference to `mdb.min.css` (you can download it from [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/download/mdb-free/440jd233sdf%5Egt4nc%28srjgzz%26x/MDB-Free.zip)).
Second, you need to limit the width of the div. like 300 px as an example (you could change it to whatever you like):

```
.card{
 width:300px;
}
```

I tried it and can see the card is same as the website.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set any width in your parent `div`. that's why div automatically shows full width. First you need to add width like below code or use `col-md-*`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.3/css/mdb.min.css">

<!--Card-->
    <div class="card" style="width: 23rem;">
    
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20%282%29.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body">
            <!--Title-->
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <!--Text-->
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the tutorial from getting started they are other css class that comes after content.  Eg container-fluid  etc.  Ensure you follow the tutorial from beginning and ensure your have the library link properly to your page or download it and try it locally. They are classes missing and card class  is supposed to have the box-shadow property while container-fluid  or content-fluid give the section the appropriate padding.  Hope this help

Comment: I agreed. It's not a pure Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of files including first of all jquery is required then bootstrap and after that mdb file should be include

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.3/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.3/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='section'>
    <!--Card-->

    <div class="card" style='width:23rem;'>
    
        <!--Card image-->
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20%282%29.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body">
            <!--Title-->
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <!--Text-->
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think the main issue is not referring mdb.min.css and not setting the width of `card` div, not the img-fluid issue.

Comment: exactly I have updated the code and its working fine.